# pthread return value error

Tags: c++

I am new to Linux programming.

I am returning a value from thread. But when compiled it is listing some errors. I am listing the code and error below. Please help me to understand why the error and how to solve it.

code

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void* compute_prime (void* arg)
{
        int x = 2;
        return (void*) x;
}


int main ()
{
        pthread_t thread;
        int prime;
        pthread_create (&thread, NULL, &compute_prime, NULL);
        pthread_join (thread, (void*) &prime);
        printf("The returned value is %d.\n", prime);
        return 0;
}
```

error

```
$ g++ -othj pdfex.cpp -lpthread
pdfex.cpp: In function `int main()':
pdfex.cpp:17: error: invalid conversion from `void*' to `void**'
pdfex.cpp:17: error:   initializing argument 2 of `int pthread_join(pthread_t, void**)'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try reposting and using the code formatting button for the sections of code, otherwise the formatting will be off.

Answer (score 4):

Since the declaration of `pthread_join()` is:

```
int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **value_ptr);
```

your '`(void *)`' cast is wrong - and the compiler is telling you that.

How to fix?

- If `sizeof(void *) == sizeof(int)` on your machine, then:

  ```
  pthread_join(thread, (void **)&prime);
  ```
- Otherwise:

  ```
  uintptr_t uip;
  pthread_join(thread, (void **)&uip);
  prime = uip;
  ```

  That requires `#include <stdint.h>` (or `#include <inttypes.h>`), and exploits the fact that a `uintptr_t` is the same size as a `void *`.

---

This code delivers the answer 2 when compiled for 64-bit on MacOS X 10.6.4 (which corresponds to the 'otherwise' clause):

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <assert.h>

static void *compute_prime(void* arg)
{
    uintptr_t x = 2;
    assert(arg == 0);
    return (void *)x;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t thread;
    uintptr_t prime;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &compute_prime, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread, (void **) &prime);
    printf("The returned value is %" PRIuPTR ".\n", prime);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: THANKS FOR UR REPLY. IT HELP ME TO SOLVE THE ERRORS

Comment: @Foo Bah: thanks, but it is a lost cause; Thanseer was last seen 2010-10-15.

Comment: @Jonathan I wasn't aware that you could actually see when people last logged in ... There's gotta be a way to forcefully mark these type of questions (there are a lot of stranded questions like this)

Comment: It was not a lost cause. Even if it didn't help him, it sure as hell helped me. I had this exact problem, and Jonathan aided me solving it. rep++

Comment: Thanks. There exist a good example as well on http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html

Answer (score 1):

pthread_join() is asking for a `void**`, and you are giving it a `void*`.