# When is casting void pointer needed in C?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, void

I've been looking at *Advanced Linux Programming* by Mitchell, Oldham and Samuel. I've seen in the section on pthreads something about void pointers and casting that confuses me.

Passing an argument to pthread_create(), they don't cast the pointer to a void pointer even though that is what the function expects.

```
pthread_create( &thread, NULL, &compute_prime, &which_prime );
```

Here, *which_prime* is of type *int*.

But taking a value returned from the thread using pthread_join, they DO cast the variable to void pointer.

```
pthread_join( thread, (void*) &prime );
```

Here, *prime* is of type *int* again.

Why is casting done in the second instance and not in the first?

Comment: `pthread_join`'s second argument is a void**.  That code looks wrong.

Comment: Looking at the full code (http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/alp-folder/alp-ch04-threads.pdf) reveals, that the example misuses the `void*` returned by the thread function and received by `pthread_join()` as `int`. This is the relevant line of `compute_prime()`: `int candidate; ... return (void*) candidate;` So using `&prime` as 2nd argument to `int prime; ... pthread_join(..., &prime)` perfectly makes sense. However casr it to `void*` simply is wrong. If placeing a cast `void**` would have been valid, as by the declaration of `pthread_join(pthread_t, void **)`.

Answer (score 15):

No need to cast from or to a pointer to `void` in C:

> **6.3.2.3 Pointers**
>
> 1 
>   A pointer to **void** may be converted to or from a pointer to any incomplete or object
>   type. A pointer to any incomplete or object type may be converted to a pointer to **void**
>   and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

---

The only exceptions from this are

- when printing a pointer using the `"%p"` conversion specifier as it's only defined for `void *`.
- when copying a pointer's value from an `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` back to a `void *`.

Comment: "when printing a pointer using the "%p" conversion specifier as it's only defined for void *" - I'm often printing non `void*` pointers using `%p` and it seems to work. Is it just not portable? Should I cast the pointers to `void*`?

Comment: @AvivCohn: "*Should I cast the pointers*" To stay compatible, yes you should, else wise undefined behaviour is invoked, which might result in (seemingly) working or crash or ....

Answer (score 12):

The second example is a good example of why casting to `void*` is usually a mistake. It should be

```
void *primep = &prime;  // no cast needed
pthread_join(thread, &primep);
```

because `pthread_join` takes a `void**` as its second argument. The `void*` only makes sure the bug passes the compiler because the `void*` is converted to `void**` automatically.

So, when *do* you need to cast to `void*` or back:

- when working with pointers stored as integers (`(u)intptr_t`);
- when passing pointers to functions that have an incomplete prototype and take `void*` (or take a different type of pointer and you have `void*`); that usually means functions taking a variable number of arguments such as `printf`.

Comment: The `void**` parameter of pthread_join is an out-parameter. It makes no sense to initialise primep. Its value will be ignored and overwritten.

Answer (score 9):

In C, casting to void* from any pointer type  **and vice-versa** is done implicitly.
There's no need for the cast in the second example.

(Note that in C++ casting any pointer to void* is also done implicitly (except for function pointers and function-member / method pointers which cannot be cast to void*), but casting back requires an explicit cast.)

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation,](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html)

```
int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **retval);
```

So, the `pthread_join` takes a `pointer to void*` as its second argument. This is because,

> In pthread_join, you get back the address passed to pthread_exit by
>   the finished thread. If you pass just a plain pointer, it is passed by
>   value so you can't change where it is pointing to. To be able to
>   change the value of the pointer passed to pthread_join, it must be
>   passed as a pointer itself, that is, a pointer to a pointer.

Now, to your question, "*Why is casting done in the second instance and not in the first?*"
In the first instance, i.e., `pthread_create`, it expects a `void*` as its fourth argument. So passing `&which_prime` would be implicitly converted to `void*`.

In the second instance, i.e., `pthread_join`, it expects a `void**` and we are passing `&prime` there. So, the compiler will complain. So, to bypass the bug, the author passes a cast of `void*` which will be automatically converted to `void**`.

But this is not a good solution.

**The Solution::**

```
void* prime ; // make prime as void*
pthread_join( thread, &prime );
printf( "%" PRIxPTR "\n", (intptr_t)prime ) ; 
// intptr_t instead of int to get an integer type 
// that's the same size as a pointer
```

Comment: Down-voted because this answer is too terse and doesn’t adequately explain the asymmetry--which is the focus of the question--to someone who doesn’t already know the answer.

Comment: @ChrisPage:: I have now included the citation. Thanks for the feed though.

Comment: I don’t see how this addresses the question “Why is casting done in the second instance and not in the first?”.

Comment: The standard quote directly contradicts the assertion above it. A ptr-to-void is incompatible with any ptr-to-function.

Comment: Your first solution will work (except %d is not the correct conversion for intptr_t) because the thread function returns an int cast to `void*`. The second solution is wrong.

Comment: @n.m. Rectified as pointed out. Yes, the second soln was plainly wrong. Hence, removed it along with the irrespective quotation cited.

Comment: @n.m. Saw your comment below Fred's answer. It definitely makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the same code has been [referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921468/pthread-return-value-error) in other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889568/why-is-this-casting-to-void-pointer-valid).

The answer in the second link explains:

> It's not valid. It simply happens to work if sizeof(int) ==
>   sizeof(void *), which happens on many systems.
>
> A void * is only guaranteed to be able to hold pointers to data
>   objects.
>
> Here is a C FAQ on the subject.

And  the quoted text:

> How are integers converted to and from pointers? Can I temporarily
>   stuff an integer into a pointer, or vice versa?
>
> Pointer-to-integer and integer-to-pointer conversions are
>   implementation-defined (see question 11.33), and there is no longer
>   any guarantee that pointers can be converted to integers and back,
>   without change
>
> Forcing pointers into integers, or integers into pointers, has never
>   been good practice

Comment: In C99 pointers can be safely converted to `intptr_t`/`uintptr_t` and back.

Comment: @FredFoo if they exist. They're optional in the standard